# Is there a way to generally search package or language documentation within emacs?

Tags: documentation, web-browser, rust

In this case, I'm most interested in Rust's documentation, which lives at doc.rust-lang.org/std. `eww` is incompatible with JS, so the documentation doesn't play nice, thus my general current soln is to just pop over to a browser. I'd be interested to know what other people do for documentation reading.

Comment: In cases like these, I usually look for how the documentation is built.  Traditionally, if a texinfo file isn't already provided, there's a Makefile which has an option to build it. It looks like the doc source is in Markdown and/or contained in docstrings (akin to Doxygen).  It's not clear to me how they compile these into the website.  Frankly, I'm getting angry seeing how non-user friendly the docs are, so I'm going to step away.  Hopefully finding how they generate the docs leads you to a more accessible format or, at least, a way to generate your own accessible copy.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions for specific languages (such as `eldoc-mode`), but since every language's documentation is in a different format and style, there is no general solution. For Rust use `lsp-mode` with either rls or rust-analyzer.